# Regex to match word on its own at beginning, or appended to something but at the end of input by not repeating the string

Tags: c++, regex

**Background**

So I am working on getting a regex that would match **hello** in the following 
cases:

**To match**

```
hello world
I am somehello
hello
somehello
```

**to NOT match**

```
I am hello world
I am somehello word
somehellow word
```

**Original regexs**

Basically, I am trying to condense these two regex rules:

```
^hello\b
hello$
```

**What I tried**

I was considering doing lookahead(positive or negative) or lookbehind(positive or negative) and match, for example, a ^ followed by \b but that would also match "helloworld something" which I do not want to match.

**Question:**

What would be the best way to combine both regular expressions into one without having to write the word out twice like this **^hello\b|hello$** ?

I am dealing with a lot of strings, not just hello, that should be matched by the regular expression, so I am trying to consume space (if functionality permits it of course).

Comment: With the question updated, I'd say there is no way to shorten the regex more than what you have. Assuming you are using C++11 `<regex>`.

Comment: I see. Yeah I am indeed using C++11. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
"^hello|hello$"
```

**EDIT:** Answer to the edited question:

If you are using Perl style regex (PCRE) then you can use the following (i have tested with `grep -P`):

```
$ grep -P "^(hello)\b|(?1)$" file.txt
hello world
I am somehello
hello
somehello
```

Here we have captured `hello` as a group and then used routine call to referred it later. (Thanks to [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) for this)

Comment: Indeed, I was just working on it as you posted it, http://puu.sh/gwqSu/2640c15506.png

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified it a bit more. I am dealing with a lot more strings that just hello so this will become just as long as separating the position matches into their own regex rules. My bad. I updated the question.

Comment: @DeDee I didn't clarify enough. Please take a look at the updated description.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: Please tag your question with the language. Different language has different level of support for regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh, good call. I updated the question with the language tag.